# Collection initializer for wrapper class and avoiding boxing of IEnumerator<T>

Tags: c#, performance, ienumerable

I have a wrapper struct for a `Dictionary` and I want to add a collection initializer to this class that adds my entries to the wrapped `Dictionary`.

```cs
public readonly struct Wrapper : IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, string>>
{
    public Dictionary<string, string> Instance { get; }

    public Wrapper()
    {
        Instance = new Dictionary<string, string>();
    }

    public void Add(string key, string value)
    {
        Instance.Add(key, value);
    }

    public IEnumerator<KeyValuePair<string, string>> GetEnumerator()
    {
        return Instance.GetEnumerator();
    }

    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return GetEnumerator();
    }
}
```

However, `GetEnumerator` call will cause boxing as `Dictionary`'s enumerator is a struct. Is there any way around this?

Comment: Are you implying that the built-in dictionary's `IEnumerable.GetEnumerator` does not box? I don't think that's the case.

Comment: You're correct, let me rephrase. I want to have the same behaviour on my wrapper class when iterating as what I will get when I iterate on the dictionary i.e. no boxing of the enumerator.

Comment: If all you want to do is make your class collection initializable, you need to implement `IEnumerable` (or the generic equivalent), buy you don't have to actually make it usable.  I've written a bunch of collection-initializable types whose `IEnumerable` implementation is just `throw new NotImplementedException()`.  Of course, if you want to allow enumeration, that's different.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The built-in `Dictionary`'s implementations of [`IEnumerable.GetEnumerator`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.dictionary-2.system-collections-ienumerable-getenumerator?view=net-7.0#system-collections-generic-dictionary-2-system-collections-ienumerable-getenumerator) and [`IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>>.GetEnumerator`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.dictionary-2.system-collections-generic-ienumerable-system-collections-generic-keyvaluepair-tkey-tvalue---getenumerator?view=net-7.0#system-collections-generic-dictionary-2-system-collections-generic-ienumerable((system-collections-generic-keyvaluepair((tkey@tvalue))))-getenumerator) box the return value too. It can't *not* do that, since `IEnumerable` requires you to return an interface type.

It's just that `Dictionary` also defines its own [`GetEnumerator`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.dictionary-2.getenumerator?view=net-7.0#system-collections-generic-dictionary-2-getenumerator), that is not required by `IEnumerable` or `IEnumerable<T>`. This `GetEnumerator` returns the struct directly, without boxing.

So when you call `GetEnumerator` through the `IEnumerator` interface, the return value will still be boxed. It's only when you call `GetEnumerator` directly on a dictionary, that it will not be boxed.

If that's what you are after, you can do what `Dictionary` does and declare three methods too:

```
IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator() => GetEnumerator();

IEnumerator<KeyValuePair<string, string>> IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, string>>.GetEnumerator()
    => GetEnumerator();

public Dictionary<string, string>.Enumerator GetEnumerator()
    => Instance.GetEnumerator();
```

See also the [source code](https://source.dot.net/#System.Private.CoreLib/src/libraries/System.Private.CoreLib/src/System/Collections/Generic/Dictionary.cs) of `Dictionary` in .NET, especially lines 1132, 365, and 367, where the 3 methods are declared.

Comment: Adding the extra method solved it.